# Tips for a shared SQL transaction with multi-threading

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions

I want different calls to share the same SQL transaction. The original idea was to keep a static pointer to the active transaction, but this is not thread save, and since I'm writing a WCF service I should consider such things. Instead of "static" I want something that is static to the current context.

```
// The main idea
public override void SaveItem()
{
    using (var transaction = BeginSharedTransaction())
    {
        other1.Save();
        base.SaveItem();
        other2.Save();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}

// In the base class
public void Save() { ... SaveItem(); ... }
protected virtual void SaveItem() { ... }

// In the base class (or another helper class)
static SqlTransaction _sqlTran = null;
public static SqlTransaction BeginSharedTransaction()
{
    _sqlTran = ... // conn.BeginTransaction();
    return _sqlTran;
}
```

If possible, I would prefer a solution that does not involve `TransactionScope`.

**EDIT** - I think we all agree that `static SqlTransaction` is bad within a service, but that was the original idea for a non-threaded environment.

Comment: Is there a scenario you could share with us where sharing the transaction is actually useful?

Comment: In my example the transaction is shared between the caller, "other1" and "other2."

Comment: You mention WCF but give no indication as to the InstanceContextMode you're using, or whether/how you're using WCF's TransasctionScopeOption attribute. WCF should be able to do a lot of this plumbing for you.

Comment: Terence, I don't know, where do I find those things?

Comment: Terence, I'd appreciate it if you could give me some advice or a link where I can find out more.

Comment: @PeetBrits, for an in-depth explanation you should check out Juval Lowy's WCF book (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596526993.do). IDesign's website also has great small sample apps showing how each of the concepts works in isolation (http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11) - note that registration may be required there. Otherwise, MSDN has a lot of technical information - you should just be able to google the class names (I made sure to spell them correctly above) to get straight to the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "sharing" you mean using the same transaction object for the SQL operations done in the base class and in the derived class, you could just move the transaction handling logic in the base class and give the derived the chance to add its own implementation, like so:

```
// In the base class
protected SqlTransaction Transaction;

public void Save() 
{ 
    ... 
    using (var transaction = BeginSharedTransaction())
    {
        Save(Transaction);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    ... 
}

public void Save(SqlTransaction transaction) 
{ 
    Transaction = transaction;
    SaveItem();
}

protected virtual void SaveItem() { ... /* uses Transaction on all SQL commands */ ... }

// in the derived class
public override void SaveItem()
{
    other1.Save(Transaction);
    base.SaveItem();
    other2.Save(Transaction);
}


// In the base class (or another helper class)
public static SqlTransaction BeginSharedTransaction()
{
    return ... // conn.BeginTransaction();
}
```

(code updated according to comments)

Comment: But then both other1.Save() and other2.Save() will attempt to begin and commit a transaction.

Comment: you're right; I missed that. I'll find a solution and update the code

Comment: I've updated the code - I propose using the `void Save(SqlTransaction transaction)` overload that allows injecting an existing transaction into a given `ClassWithUnknownNameThatDoesSomeSqlStuff` instance

Comment: this should work provided that the current instance as well as other 1 and other2 are not shared across multiple requests (I guess sharing these across request wouldn't make much sense)

Comment: That should work. Just for curiosity / best practice, do you think it's a good idea to start a transaction for every call even if it won't need it (e.g. single calls)? In my original post I tried to do something where the transaction will only happen when needed.

Comment: I think it induces a slight overhead, but wouldn't worry about it unless I try the application and see that it's indeed a performance issue.